# Soundcloud : Issue with API linked_partioning

Tags: soundcloud

Is there an issue with the linked_partitioning functionality of the soundcloud API

I have done further testing and the functionality behaves as expected for some of the API, but does not work in the following areas I have verified so far using an oAuth token and the /me resource (the token is valid and refreshed as needed) :

followers
following

Example :

https://api.soundcloud.com/me/followings?oauth_token=TOKEN&limit=50&linked_partitioning=1

This was previously returning data with the "next_href" field populated but now it returns

Using PHP json_decode on the data it shows

[next_href] =>

The raw Json is now

"next_href":null}

Comment: can u tell us the user who is me? for me its working fine.

Comment: It is the currently logged in user using oAuth and a valid token.

It only seems to be happening via the /me resource and only for followers and following as I can tell so far.

I have changed the limit parameter to 5 in testing so it should return data for followers (which is 16 for the user) and it shows nothing. The # followed by the user is > 100 so that should have been showing at 50.

This was working yesterday as I am working on pagination and testing against the returned value of next_href to determine whether or not to display "More..." with a clickable link.

Comment: I also checked the return value for /me/activities where the limit is set to 200 (I am not supporting pagination there at this point, but am passing the linked_partioning parameter) and the field is populated:

Debugged using php json_decode to a log file in all cases

[next_href] => https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities?limit=200&cursor=00000151-a214-b1e0-ffff-ffffc83f0a2c

Comment: This is for the same user using the client_id and /user resource and gives me the same result

https://api.soundcloud.com/users/188504309/followings?&limit=50&linked_partitioning=1&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID